# <img id="background">.. nothing showing up?

Tags: html, css, image, background

I just dont get why the background is on top of the text..
I'd really appreciate ANY help..

THX

```
 html


<body>
...
<img...>
    <div>
        <div> 
       drop down list
         <div>
    <div>

body>img{
```

heres the background options, wanted it to adjust in height and width
                  /* Set rules to fill background */
                  min-height: 100%;
                  min-width: 1024px;

```
              /* Set up proportionate scaling */
              width: 100%;
              height: auto;

              /* Set up positioning */
              position: fixed;
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
            }




            #wrap{
                max-width: 1000px;
                margin: 20px 0px;
                display:-webkit-box;
                -webkit-box-flex: 1;
                padding-top: 30px;
            }


            /* link styles und so */
            a:hover{
                cursor:pointer;
            }

            a{
                text-decoration: none;
                font-family: 'Sintony', sans-serif;
                color:black;
            }


            /* drop down list */

            .clear{
                clear:both;
            }

            ul#nav{
                list-style-type: none;
                padding: 0;
                margin-top:60px;

            }

            ul#nav li{
                background-color: white;
                float:left;
            }

            ul#nav li a{
                display:block;
                padding: 5px 10px;
                color:#000;
                text-decoration: none;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
                list-style-type: none;
            }


            ul#nav li a:hover{
                background-color: #aaa;
            }

            ul#nav li ul li{
                float: none;
                list-style-type: none;
            }

            ul#nav li ul{
                position: absolute;
                display:none;
            }

            ul#nav li:hover ul{
                display: block;
            }
```

Comment: Can you create a demo like JSBin so we can see exactly the problem you're using? Some of your generalizations here may in fact be the problem, but it's hard to say. The more info you give the better the answer you'll get!

Comment: Welcome on SO! I edited the title of your question to remove "kinda hard to ask i guess" and "what's wrong with (...)": please keep as concise as possible by just describing your problem

Comment: wow, this community is **SUPERB**

thank you guys, will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the background using CSS

body
{
background-image:url('yourfilepath');
background-color:#cccccc;
}

If you don't want to use background-image element, and you want to use the img element, then you should work with the z-index property. Here you can play with it.

Here the example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex